# Restore weights from chekpoints Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I'm working with tensorflow object detection API and I followed their tutorial at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb.

The problem is that I want to train a Faster R-CNN but I don't know how to load from chekpoint the pretrainded weights.
The following code (reported from tutorial) must be adapted for the purpose, but I don't know how.. I don't found any reference or documentation.

```
# Set up object-based checkpoint restore --- RetinaNet has two prediction
# `heads` --- one for classification, the other for box regression.  We will
# restore the box regression head but initialize the classification head
# from scratch (we show the omission below by commenting out the line that
# we would add if we wanted to restore both heads)
fake_box_predictor = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
    _base_tower_layers_for_heads=detection_model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads,
    # _prediction_heads=detection_model._box_predictor._prediction_heads,
    #    (i.e., the classification head that we *will not* restore)
    _box_prediction_head=detection_model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head,
    )
fake_model = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
          _feature_extractor=detection_model._feature_extractor,
          _box_predictor=fake_box_predictor)
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=fake_model)
ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).expect_partial()
```

Comment: Here you may find the [Faster_rcnn](https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1) model details. Thanks!

Comment: As for the checkpoint restore, follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#checkpoint_callback_options) to get more information. Thanks

Comment: detection_model doesn't have load_weights method